# error: no matching function for call to Counter::Counter()

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm getting this error when I try to compile an Arduino sketch.  I don't see where it thinks I'm trying to call `Counter::Counter` without arguments.  What's going on here?

```
sketch/periodic_effect.cpp: In constructor 'PeriodicEffect::PeriodicEffect(uint32_t, uint32_t, Counter::Mode)':
periodic_effect.cpp:4: error: no matching function for call to 'Counter::Counter()'
 PeriodicEffect::PeriodicEffect( uint32_t durationMs, uint32_t periods, Counter::Mode mode) : Runnable(), periods(periods) {
```

**periodic_effect.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "periodic_effect.h"

PeriodicEffect::PeriodicEffect( uint32_t durationMs, uint32_t periods, Counter::Mode mode) : Runnable(), periods(periods) {
  intervalMs = durationMs / periods;
  index = Counter(intervalMs, mode);
}


void PeriodicEffect::run() {
  uint32_t currTimeMs = millis();
  if( (currTimeMs - prevTimeMs) > intervalMs ) {
    applyChange();
    prevTimeMs = currTimeMs;
    index.increment();
  }
}
```

**periodic_effect.h**

```
#ifndef PERIODIC_EFFECT_H
#define PERIODIC_EFFECT_H

#include "counter.h"
#include "runnable.h"

class PeriodicEffect : public Runnable {

  public:
    PeriodicEffect( uint32_t durationMs, uint32_t periods, Counter::Mode mode = Counter::Mode::RESETTING );

    Counter index;

  private:
    uint32_t intervalMs, periods, prevTimeMs;

    virtual void applyChange() = 0;
    void run();
    virtual void setup() = 0;
};

#endif
```

**counter.h**

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <stdint.h>


class Counter {
  public:
    enum Mode { RESETTING, RETURNING };
    Counter(uint32_t limit, Counter::Mode mode = RESETTING, uint32_t index = 0);

    uint32_t getIndex();
    void increment();
    float percent();

  private:
    bool goingForward;
    uint32_t index;
    const uint32_t limit;
    Counter::Mode mode;

    void incrementReturning();
    void incrementResetting();

};

#endif
```

**counter.cpp**

```
#include "counter.h"

Counter::Counter(uint32_t limit, Counter::Mode mode, uint32_t index) : index(index), limit(limit), mode(mode) {
  goingForward = true;
}


uint32_t Counter::getIndex() {
  return index;
}


void Counter::increment() {
  switch( mode ) {
    case RESETTING : incrementResetting();
    case RETURNING : incrementReturning();
  }
}


void Counter::incrementResetting() {
  index = (index + 1) % limit;
}


void Counter::incrementReturning() {
  if( goingForward ) {
    index++;
    if( index >= limit ) {
      index = limit - 1;
      goingForward = false;
    }
  } else {
    index--;
    if( index <= 0 ) {
      index = 1;
      goingForward = true;
    }
  }
}


float Counter::percent() {
  return (float) index / (float) limit;
}
```

Comment: Add a default constructor to your counter object.

Comment: Why is that necessary?

Comment: Because you declared: Counter index; in your PeriodicEffect class. It is the default ctor which is called to initialize your member

Comment: By declaring `Counter(uint32_t limit, Counter::Mode mode = RESETTING, uint32_t index = 0);`, the default constructor is no longer automatically generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `PeriodicEffect` has a `Counter` member variable, and no constructor. This means the member variable will need to be default constructed, i.e. constructed by a constructor with no parameters. You haven't supplied one.

You can either give `Counter` a default constructor, or let the existing constructor have defaults for *all* of the parameters. Or you can make a `PeriodicEffect` constructor with an initializer list to provide the proper parameters to `index`.

Comment: Updated my code to call `index = Counter(intervalMs, mode)` in the `PeriodicEffect` constructor.  Same error.

Comment: @DeanBrundage read again what I wrote. It's not enough to assign `index` in the *body* of the constructor, you must do it in the *initializer list*.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Why can I initialize the `intervalMs` member variable in the constructor but not `index`?

Comment: @DeanBrundage all member variables are initialized before the start of the constructor, either as part of the initializer list or by using the default for that type. The assignment of `intervalMs` *changes* the value at a later point.

Answer (score 1):

```
PeriodicEffect::PeriodicEffect(
    uint32_t durationMs, uint32_t periods, Counter::Mode mode) :
    Runnable(), periods(periods) { /* ... */
```

`PeriodicEffect` has a member `Counter index;`.  Since `index` is not in the member initializer list of this constructor, it gets default constructed.

The statement

```
index = Counter(intervalMs, mode);
```

inside the constructor is an assignment, not an initialization.  Too late.